# How to open different activities on item selected on drop down menu on the toolbar

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have searched for this over the internet and haven't found appropriate answers. I am loading a spinner drop down menu on my toolbar which contains items that open different activities after being selected. So far I have been able to create a toast which returns the name of the selected item. But I would like to open different activities for each item on the menu. I know this might be a duplicate somewhere but their answers haven't worked for mine yet.
This is my spinner:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And this is my MainActivity.java

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        final Spinner spinner_navs = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_nav);

        SpinnerAdapter mSpinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                (this, R.array.action_bar_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_navs.setAdapter(mSpinner);
        spinner_navs.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I know I am a newbie, but any help on this I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just switch between *id*.
 switch(id){
case 1:
Intent x = new Intent();
startActivity(x);
break;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
spinner_nav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
     int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item

    if(position==0){
        // open activity 1
    }else if(position==1){
        // open activity 2
    }
    else if(position==2){
        // open activity 3
    }
   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Switch statement

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    switch (position) {

                case 1:

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("yourkeyone", string);
                    break;

                case 2:

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("yourkeytwo", string);
                    break;

                   //ect...
}   
return true;
}
```